# Is there a programmatic interface to the Windows wireless network report?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, netsh, wifi

That is the report generated with command prompt command:

`netsh wlan show wlanreport`

which writes a report file out to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WLANReport\WLAN-report-latest.html. References:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4000462/windows-10-analyzing-wireless-network-report

https://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-fixes-single-notification-error-latest-windows-10-slow-ring-build

I would like to get that type of data programmatically (via .NET/C#, win APIs, WMI, or Powershell) and ideally not in the form of an HTML file to then parse. But I'll take what I can get. Worse case might be to shell execute a call to that command to generate the report.

Or is the programmatic alternative to call a bunch of different APIs to get the complete set of info instead of a single call/command like this netsh one?

Comment: Generate this report seems not what one API can complete. By default, `netsh wlan show wlanreport` will generate a report for wireless activity over the
    last three days based on the **event log** on your system. So you can enable diagnostic at `Event Viewer -> Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Wlan-AutoConfig or WlanConn` to see if it can get information you are looking for? If, yes, you can use [Windows Event Log Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/windows-event-log-functions) to generate report by yourself.